# i am having problem in wordpress attorna theme header section

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, when I open my site on the computer, the phone number appears between the logo on the far left and the search icon on the far right in the header section of the attorna theme. But this number does not appear next to the logo on mobile. I want it to appear, how can I do that?

Comment: Please add relevant screenshots, current styles and the styles you've tried to fix it. This would help members to suggest you a solution.

Comment: You can either add media queries and style those in your mobile. Or check the theme customize section to find is there any option for mobile devices to adjust these.